# ionic / vue / capacitor local notification retrieve more than notification id

Tags: vue.js, ionic4, capacitor, localnotification, capacitor-plugin

I'm using the LocalNotifications plugin from capacitor core. Is there anyway of retrieving details, such as title and the schedule, of still pending notifications. The method getPending()  seems to only return a list of id's.

Answer (score 1):

it look like we are in the same boat (like many others). I only recently switched from Cordova to Capacitor just for `LocalNotification`, as the Corodova plugin is essentially pointless and now we have this.

For now, I ended up with keeping track of the Notifications I create in a locally maintained dictionary. A little tedious but does the work. I did however find this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1796) that has been marked as an `enhancement`on the GitHub repo. Make sure to show your support so that we can have this in the next release asap.

Its funny how they were kind enough to throw in the `extra` param in the LocalNotification object which seemed perfect for what I was trying to do. Unfortunately, they left no way to access it ever again :(

Comment: Yep, saw that as well. I actually created the feature request, which is linked another related [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/pull/211), to the dev team around the same time that I made this post. Looking forward to using Capacitor 3 when it comes out. In the meantime, however, I'm relying on just push notification from the server side.

Comment: This request looks gold so thanks for sharing. Definitely looking forward to Capacitor 3 release version!